# ChoiceBox iteration in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a next code `jsp` file:

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: __it
  Date: 08.04.2019
  Time: 14:00
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
The stuent is confirmed: ${student.firstName} ${student.lastName} 
<br><br>
Country: ${student.country}
<br><br>
Favourite language: ${student.favLnguage}
<br><br>
Operating system(s):
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="temp" items="${student.operatingSystems}">
    <li>${temp}"</li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in line 31 I try iterate over `operatingSystem` array.
In Student class it looks like:

```
 private String[] operatingSystems;
```

When I run server, after choice my `operatingSystems` i have a next results:
[image]

As you can see iteration is not working in browser, but in idea I have sout of my OS. I made sout to make sure that after choicing of OS it doesn't return null.

My Choice Box:

```
<p> Operating systems </p>
Linux <form:checkbox path="operatingSystems" value="Linux"/>
Mac OS <form:checkbox path="operatingSystems" value="MacOS"/>
Windows <form:checkbox path="operatingSystems" value="Wimdows OS"/>
```

**Update:**
for Anthony
[image]

**My Pom XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringgMVC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jsp-api -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you debug method *setOperatingSystem(String[] operatingSystems)* after submit form? What is there?

Comment: Yes, in console after pressing submit, I have all OS witch I have choose. That means, setOperatingSystem(String[] operatingSystems) works correctly. Problem in jsp. When I try to add (<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>) in jsp file, I have message: Can not resolve taglib with uri uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core". When I add it with Maven, it shows me result as in the picture

Answer (score 0):

I saw incorrect entry in comment above (I didn't see ***http://*** at url). Although it could be done accidentally.
Anyway try to replace it to this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

For support jstl

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I add like you show? but message is same. I added print screen in my question

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml?

Comment: @AndriyOstashevskiy Did you try add dependency for support jstl? Code attached to answer above

Comment: It was my first action, but it didn't see form:c

Comment: After add entry in pom.xml, do you have appropriate entry in project? Screen attached. Anyway you can try add this library manually through File - Project Structure - Libraries-Click '+' - Choose jstl jar file (for Intellij)

Comment: Yes? I did this, but when I add lib in project struct and In .jsp, I have error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application. When I delete it from .jsp (<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>) it doesn't do iteration and show resultas in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't use `<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`, but I use iteration in jsp file.

```
    Operating system(s):
<table>
<% String[] system = (String[]) request.getAttribute("os");
    for (int i = 0; i < system.length; i++) {
        String os = system[i];
     %>
    <tr>
        <td><%out.print(os);%></td>
    </tr>
    <%}%>
</table>
```

In controller class I have to create an array, and `setAttribute("array", array);`
Yes, this is hard code, but it's the only one decision witch I founded.